# Custom Hive SerDe unable to SELECT column but works when I do SELECT *

Tags: hadoop, hive, thrift, hive-serde

I'm writing a custom SerDe and will only be using it to deserialize.
The underlying data is a thrift binary, each row is an event log. Each event has a schema which i have access to, but we wrap the event in another schema, let's call it `Message` before storing.
The reason I'm writing a SerDe instead of using the [ThriftDeserializer](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/serde/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/thrift/ThriftDeserializer.java) is because as mentioned the underlying event is wrapped as a Message. So we first need to deserialize using the schema of `Message` and then deserialize the data for that event.

The SerDe works (only) when I do a `SELECT *` and I can deserialize the data as expected but whenever I select a column from the table instead of a SELECT *, the rows are all NULL. The object inspector returned is a `ThriftStructObjectInspector` and the Object returned by the deserialize is a TBase.

**What could cause Hive to return NULL when we select a column, but return the column data when I do a SELECT * ?**

Here's the SerDe class (changed some classnames):

```
public class MyThriftSerde extends AbstractSerDe {

  private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MyThriftSerde.class);

  /* Abstracting away the deserialization of the underlying event which is wrapped in a message */
  private static final MessageDeserializer myMessageDeserializer =
      MessageDeserializer.getInstance();

  /* Underlying event class which is wrapped in a Message */
  private String schemaClassName;
  private Class<?> schemaClass;

  /* Used to read the input row */
  public static List<String> inputFieldNames;
  public static List<ObjectInspector> inputFieldOIs;
  public static List<Integer> notSkipIDs;
  public static ObjectInspector inputRowObjectInspector;

  /* Output Object Inspector */
  public static ObjectInspector thriftStructObjectInspector;

  @Override
  public void initialize(Configuration conf, Properties tbl) throws SerDeException {
    try {

      logHeading("INITIALIZE MyThriftSerde");

      schemaClassName = tbl.getProperty(SERIALIZATION_CLASS);
      schemaClass = conf.getClassByName(schemaClassName);

      LOG.info(String.format("Building DDL for event: %s", schemaClass.getName()));

      inputFieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
      inputFieldOIs = new ArrayList<>();
      notSkipIDs = new ArrayList<>();

      /* Initialize the Input fields */

      // The underlying data is stored in RCFile format, and only has 1 column, event_binary
      // So we create a ColumnarStructBase for each row we deserialize.
      // This ColumnasStruct only has 1 column: event_binary
      inputFieldNames.add("event_binary");
      notSkipIDs.add(0);
      inputFieldOIs.add(LazyPrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.LAZY_BINARY_OBJECT_INSPECTOR);
      inputRowObjectInspector =
          ObjectInspectorFactory.getColumnarStructObjectInspector(inputFieldNames, inputFieldOIs);

      /* Output Object Inspector*/

      // This is what the SerDe will return, it is a ThriftStructObjectInspector
      thriftStructObjectInspector =
          ObjectInspectorFactory.getReflectionObjectInspector(
              schemaClass, ObjectInspectorFactory.ObjectInspectorOptions.THRIFT);

      // Only for debugging
      logHeading("THRIFT OBJECT INSPECTOR");
      LOG.info("Output OI Class Name: " + thriftStructObjectInspector.getClass().getName());
      LOG.info(
          "OI Details: "
              + ObjectInspectorUtils.getObjectInspectorName(thriftStructObjectInspector));

    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.info("Exception while initializing SerDe", e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Object deserialize(Writable rowWritable) throws SerDeException {

    logHeading("START DESERIALIZATION");

    ColumnarStructBase inputLazyStruct =
        new ColumnarStruct(inputRowObjectInspector, notSkipIDs, null);
    LazyBinary eventBinary;
    Message rowAsMessage;
    TBase deserializedRow = null;

    try {
      inputLazyStruct.init((BytesRefArrayWritable) rowWritable);
      eventBinary = (LazyBinary) inputLazyStruct.getField(0);
      rowAsMessage =
          myMessageDeserializer.fromBytes(eventBinary.getWritableObject().copyBytes(), null);
      deserializedRow = rowAsMessage.getEvent();

      LOG.info("deserializedRow.getClass(): " + deserializedRow.getClass());
      LOG.info("deserializedRow.toString(): " + deserializedRow.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    logHeading("END DESERIALIZATION");

    return deserializedRow;
  }

  private void logHeading(String s) {
    LOG.info(String.format("-------------------  %s  -------------------", s));
  }

  @Override
  public ObjectInspector getObjectInspector() {
    return thriftStructObjectInspector;
  }
}
```

Context on the code:

1. In the underlying data, each row contains only 1 column (called event_binary), stored as a binary. The binary is a Message which contains 2 fields, "schema" + "event_data". i.e. each row is a Message which contains the underlying event's schema + data. We use the schema from Message to deserialize the data.
2. The SerDe first deserializes the row as a Message, extracts the event data and then deserializes the event.

I create an EXTERNAL table which points to the Thrift data using

```
ADD JAR hdfs://my-jar.jar;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dev_db.thrift_event_data_deserialized
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.test.only.MyThriftSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "serialization.class"="com.test.only.TestEvent"
) STORED AS RCFILE
LOCATION 'location/of/thrift/data';

MSCK REPAIR TABLE thrift_event_data_deserialized;
```

Then `SELECT * FROM dev_db.thrift_event_data_deserialized LIMIT 10;` works as expected 
But, `SELECT column1_name, column2_name FROM dev_db.thrift_event_data_deserialized LIMIT 10;` does not work.

Any idea what i'm missing here? Would love any help on this!

Comment: Since your DDL actually comes from deserializer, Hive may not recognize columns when you call them by name. My suggestion is to create table with `select *` query and see what columns names deserializer produces.

Comment: The DDL is generated using the `schemaClass` in the initialize method. 
The SerDe generates the DDL as expected - equivalent to the Thrift schema of the underlying event class (referenced in the code as schemaClass)

`SELECT column1_name, column2_name FROM dev_db.thrift_event_data_deserialized ` was as an example, I am using the correct column name which is produced by the deserializer.
@serge_k

Comment: How about `describe formatted dev_db.thrift_event_data_deserialized`, what does it show? anyway, did you try to create table and see the column names? Hive might end up producing `struct` for your schemaClass instead of separated columns.